# Is there a ContinuationToken for Azure.Storage.Queue in version 12+

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I'm working on a Access layer to connect my program to the azure queue storage and get a list of all queues. I'm using the Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueServiceClient to get all queues and list then.

this is what im trying to do:

```
public IEnumerable<QueueItem> GetQueueList()
    {
        var queues = new List<QueueItem>();
        var serviceClient = new QueueServiceClient(_connectionStrings.myConnectionString);            
        var queues = serviceClient.GetQueues();
        QueueContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        do
        {
            var queue = queues.AsPages(continuationToken);
            continuationToken = queue.ContinuationToken;
            queues.AddRange(queue);
        }
        while (continuationToken != null);
        return queues;
```

What I'm needing is something similar to the QueueContinuationToken from version 11, but I'm not able to find anything related, just the deprecated version of the continuation token.

---

### UPDATE

I've found a way to work arround this, but it has nothing to do with the ContinuationToken.

The code looks like this

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<QueueItem>> GetQueueListAsync()
    {                        
        var queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(_connectionStrings.MyConnectionString);
        IAsyncEnumerable<Page<QueueItem>> queues = queueServiceClient.GetQueuesAsync().AsPages();
        var result = new List<QueueItem>();           
        await foreach(var page in queues)
        {
            foreach (var queue in page.Values)
            {
                result.Add(queue);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I believe you can simplify your code by **foreach(var queue in queues)**. The library will automatically page results.

Comment: That helps me clean up some code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by John in the comment section , one may try  **foreach(var queue in queues)** to get queue list which simplifies the code.

Thanks [@john Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) for your answer.